How to setup VSCode encoding/charset for whole project/workspace?
I work on a project which uses latin1 encoding. How can I setup VSCode to use it no matter what machine, OS or local config it's running on?

Create a .vscode/settings.json file containing { "files.encoding": "iso88591" } and make sure it's not on .gitignore.
cd project
mkdir .vscode && cat > .vscode/settings.json <<EOF
{
  "files.encoding": "iso88591"
}
EOF

